# JavaScript for setting up cookies

Tags: javascript, inline

I wrote some JS code for setting up cookies, but it does not work and I do not know why. Can somebody help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setcookie(c_name, cvalue){
var now = now.getDate();
now.setMonth(now.getMonth() +1 )
ex = now.toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'expire day is' + ex+'c_name = ' + c_name +  cvalue

}
function getcookie(c_name)
{
var allcookies = document.cookie
document.write(allcookies)
var spli = allcookies.split(';')
for (i=0 ;i < spli.length; i++){
name = spli[i].split('=')[0];
value = spli[i].split('=')[1];   
document.write('name' +name + 'value'+value)
                         } 
}
function checkcookie() {
username = getCookie(username)
if (username !=null &&  username !=''){
  alert('hello again ' + username)
                           }
else {
username = prompt('ENTER')
alert('heloo' + username)
if (user != "" && user != null) {
setCookie('user',username , 30)
      }
    }     
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkcookie()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any error? What is not working? Please provide more information

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. So open the console to see that `getCookie` and `getcookie` is not the same. Second, `user` and `username` is not the same variable, so if you use `username = prompt('ENTER')`, you have to use username instead of user here as well: `if (user != "" && user != null) {`. Third: username is global, so yo get an error to state you have to add `var` somewhere. Fourth: `var now = now.getDate();`, you can't call now.getDate() when `now` does not exist yet. Please fix all the errors the console tells you, i haven't arrived at the last error yet, so no solution code yet.